# Wordpress automatically removes <p> (paragraph) and <br /> (line-break) tags from my posts

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

first let me give a bit of background. I am a front-end developer and have never used wordpress before and don't know php either. I got a task in my company regarding formatting issues in our wordpress articles. So i got access to the wordpress dashboard and saw that we have many custom "post types" (as they are called) added in there.

We add a new article by using the editor. So in one of these custom post type there is a problem that when i add text in it and publish it the `<p>` and `<br/>` tags are removed from the output html that i see on the url. This is undesirable as paragraphs and line-breaks are very much required.

This automatic removal of `<p>` and `<br/>` doesn't happen for other post types. So i guess there must be a template or something set for it. I don't know where to edit such a setting.

I would be greateful on some guidance here on how to find the solution to my problem. Please also refer to the added screenshots.

1. [WordPress Editor View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jdey6.png)
2. [WordPress Source Code View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwQ0X.png)
3. [Actual HTML received on published URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0Jzy.png)

I saw a solution that this had something to do with wpautop filter or something and i needed to add a line of code on my `functions.php` but was not really sure if that was the correct solution.